# Reduce Key with Ordered List of Values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following RDD:

```
| Key | Value | Date       |
|-----|-------|------------|
| 1   | A     | 10/30/2016 |
| 1   | B     | 10/31/2016 |
| 1   | C     | 11/1/2016  |
| 1   | D     | 11/2/2016  |
| 2   | A     | 11/2/2016  |
| 2   | B     | 11/2/2016  |
| 2   | C     | 11/2/2016  |
| 3   | A     | 10/30/2016 |
| 3   | B     | 10/31/2016 |
| 3   | C     | 11/1/2016  |
| 3   | D     | 11/2/2016  |
```

And I would like to transform it to the following RDD:

```
| Key | List         |
|-----|--------------|
| 1   | (A, B, C, D) |
| 2   | (A, B, C)    |
| 3   | (A, B, C, D) |
```

Which is Key, List(Value) -- where the list of Values is ordered by the corresponding dates. All keys, obviously, will be unique, but not all values will necessarily be unique. I would still like to list all Values. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You should try before you ask questions on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Create a model to represent the data (you can use tuples as well, but coding with tuples would become ugly very soon. Its always good to have names for the fields)

```
case class DataItem(key: Int, value: String, timeInMillis: Long)
```

then

parse the data (you can use joda DateTimeFormat for parsing DateTime) and then create your rdd

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(DataItem(1, "A", 123), DataItem(2, "B", 1234), DataItem(2, "C", 12345)))
```

and then final step `groupBy` key and sortBy time

```
rdd.groupBy(_.key).map { case (k, v) => k -> v.toList.sortBy(_.timeInMillis)}
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> case class DataItem(key: Int, value: String, timeInMillis: Long)
defined class DataItem

scala> sc.parallelize(List(DataItem(1, "A", 123), DataItem(2, "B", 1234), DataItem(2, "C", 12345)))
res10: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[DataItem] = ParallelCollectionRDD[12] at parallelize at <console>:36

scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(DataItem(1, "A", 123), DataItem(2, "B", 1234), DataItem(2, "C", 12345)))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[DataItem] = ParallelCollectionRDD[13] at parallelize at <console>:35

scala> rdd.groupBy(_.key).map { case (k, v) => k -> v.toList.sortBy(_.timeInMillis)}
res11: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, List[DataItem])] = MapPartitionsRDD[16] at map at <console>:38

scala> rdd.groupBy(_.key).map { case (k, v) => k -> v.toList.sortBy(_.timeInMillis)}.foreach(println)
(1,List(DataItem(1,A,123)))
(2,List(DataItem(2,B,1234), DataItem(2,C,12345)))

scala> rdd.groupBy(_.key).map { case (k, v) => k -> v.toList.sortBy(_.timeInMillis)}.map { case (k, v) => (k, v.map(_.value)) }.foreach(println)
(1,List(A))
(2,List(B, C))
```